# Show a table conditionally in Angular

Tags: angular

I am working on a project and I need to show a table that gets data and is filled automatically once the data is entered.
I want that when I open a case in every type of loan to show that table except when I open a Micro Loan to add me an extra `<td></td>`.
Below is my code for this:

```
<div [formGroup]="collateralSummaryData">

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th class="table-us50"></th>
            <th class="table-us50" colspan="6">Internal Appraiser</th>
            <th class="table-us50" colspan="1">Risk Analyst</th>
            <th class="table-us50" colspan="3">CDD Specialist</th>
            <th class="table-us50" colspan="1"></th>
        </tr>

        <td class="table-us36">Nr.</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Time collateral registration process/ Koha e regjistrimit te procesit te kolateralit</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Collateral Type/ Tipi kolateralit</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Property number/ Numri I pasurise</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Property name/ Emri i pasurise</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Other details/Detaje te tjera</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Vlera e prones varet ne menyre materiale nga kapaciteti I kredimarresit</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Risku i klientit varet ne menyre materiale nga performanca e prones/projektit</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Prona eshte regjistruar ne favor te bankes</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Prona konvertohet ne cash brenda nje kohe te arsyeshme</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Kontrata e hipotekes paraqet nje titull ekzekutiv per pasurine</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Name of owner/ Emri i zoteruesit</td>

        <tr formArrayName="COLLATERAL_BRANCH" *ngFor="let collateralBranch of collateralSummaryData['controls']['COLLATERAL_BRANCH']['controls']; let i=index">

            <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                <td class="table-us36">{{i + 1}}</td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_INTERNAL_APPRAISER.TIME_COL_REG}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_INTERNAL_APPRAISER.IA_COL_TYPE}}
                </td>

              <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_INTERNAL_APPRAISER.IA_PROPERTY_NO}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_INTERNAL_APPRAISER.IA_PROPERTY_NAME}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_INTERNAL_APPRAISER.IA_OTHER_DETAILS}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_INTERNAL_APPRAISER.IA_HOW_PROPERTY_IS_MEASURED}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_RISK_ANALYST.RA_CLIENT_RISK}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_CCD_SPECIALIST.CDD_PROPERTY_REGISTRATION}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_CCD_SPECIALIST.CDD_PROPERTY_CONVERT_TO_CASH}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_CCD_SPECIALIST.CDD_MORTGAGE_CONTRACT}}
                </td>
                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_CCD_SPECIALIST.CDD_NAME_OF_OWNER}}
                </td>

            </ng-container>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have add this at .ts

```
get isMicro(){
      let productItems =  <FormArray>(<FormGroup>(<FormGroup>(this.documentService.documentForm.controls['PRODUCTS_INFO'])).controls['PRODUCT_ITEM_S']).controls['PRODUCT_ITEM'] ;
      let productId = (<FormGroup>(<FormGroup>productItems.controls[0]).controls['GENERAL_PRODUCT_DATA']).controls['PRODUCT_DATA_PRODUCT_ID'].value;
      if(productId == "10") //tobechanged
      return true;
    return false;
  }
```

I know that I have to add an `*ngIf="isMicro"` somewhere but don't know where!

Comment: which table are you trying to hide? can you make a comment on the code you have to include something like "I'm trying to hide this table"

Comment: @Goku table is the same I want to add and extra column only at that case when i open Micro Loan

Comment: oh gotcha. I'll edit my answer

Comment: add your *ngIf as an attribute to your <td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: obviously, you'll change this to add more `<td>` elements to make more columns, but for brevity I'll just edit the `<th>` and give you an idea of how to use the ifelse in this case.

The way I would probably do it is to to have your code almost identical in both places of the conditional and have an if else divide up the code. this way you can play with alignment to make sure they both look correct for their unique cases.

```
<div [formGroup]="collateralSummaryData">

            <table class="table" *ngIf="isMicro(); else else_statment">
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-us50"></th>
                    <th class="table-us50" colspan="6">Internal Appraiser</th>
                    <th class="table-us50" colspan="1">Risk Analyst</th>
                    <th class="table-us50" colspan="3">CDD Specialist</th>
                    <th class="table-us50" colspan="1"></th>
                    <th class="table-microcolumn" colspan="1"></th>
                </tr>
               ... etc
             </table>
  <ng-template #else_statment>
    <div [formGroup]="collateralSummaryData">

            <table class="table" *ngIf="isMicro(); else else_statment">
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-us50"></th>
                    <th class="table-us50" colspan="6">Internal Appraiser</th>
                    <th class="table-us50" colspan="1">Risk Analyst</th>
                    <th class="table-us50" colspan="3">CDD Specialist</th>
                    <th class="table-us50" colspan="1"></th>
                    <th class="table-microcolumn" colspan="1"></th>
                </tr>
             ... etc
  </ng-template>
```

A simple answer (but things may not line up how you want) is to just add your wanted column if isMicro() evaluates to true.

```
<div [formGroup]="collateralSummaryData">

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th class="table-us50"></th>
            <th class="table-us50" colspan="6">Internal Appraiser</th>
            <th class="table-us50" colspan="1">Risk Analyst</th>
            <th class="table-us50" colspan="3">CDD Specialist</th>
            <th class="table-us50" colspan="1"></th>
            <th class="table-us50" colspan="1" *ngIf="isMicro()"></th>
        </tr>

        <td class="table-us36">Nr.</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Time collateral registration process/ Koha e regjistrimit te procesit te kolateralit</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Collateral Type/ Tipi kolateralit</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Property number/ Numri I pasurise</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Property name/ Emri i pasurise</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Other details/Detaje te tjera</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Vlera e prones varet ne menyre materiale nga kapaciteti I kredimarresit</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Risku i klientit varet ne menyre materiale nga performanca e prones/projektit</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Prona eshte regjistruar ne favor te bankes</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Prona konvertohet ne cash brenda nje kohe te arsyeshme</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Kontrata e hipotekes paraqet nje titull ekzekutiv per pasurine</td>
        <td class="table-us36">Name of owner/ Emri i zoteruesit</td>

        <tr formArrayName="COLLATERAL_BRANCH" *ngFor="let collateralBranch of collateralSummaryData['controls']['COLLATERAL_BRANCH']['controls']; let i=index">

            <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                <td class="table-us36">{{i + 1}}</td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_INTERNAL_APPRAISER.TIME_COL_REG}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_INTERNAL_APPRAISER.IA_COL_TYPE}}
                </td>

              <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_INTERNAL_APPRAISER.IA_PROPERTY_NO}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_INTERNAL_APPRAISER.IA_PROPERTY_NAME}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_INTERNAL_APPRAISER.IA_OTHER_DETAILS}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_INTERNAL_APPRAISER.IA_HOW_PROPERTY_IS_MEASURED}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_RISK_ANALYST.RA_CLIENT_RISK}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_CCD_SPECIALIST.CDD_PROPERTY_REGISTRATION}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_CCD_SPECIALIST.CDD_PROPERTY_CONVERT_TO_CASH}}
                </td>

                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_CCD_SPECIALIST.CDD_MORTGAGE_CONTRACT}}
                </td>
                <td class="table-us36">
                    {{collateralBranch.value.COLLATERAL_ELIGIBILITY_CCD_SPECIALIST.CDD_NAME_OF_OWNER}}
                </td>

            </ng-container>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Simple incomplete overview of ngIf* vs ngShow*:

if you're trying to remove the DOM elements of the entire table, you can use *ngIf

(what looks to be your second line in the HTML)

```
<table class="table" *ngIf="!isMicro()">
```

if you're trying to just "hide" the table and keep them in the DOM you can use *ngIf

```
<table class="table" *ngShow="!isMicro()">
```

Decide on which one to use will be based on how this page is used and what you are tying to do. One example is if you are needing to unhide and hide very frequently. If that was the case, *ngShow is less expensive on the performance side of things.